# execute sql query with sandbox/isolation

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

Is that a way to execute SQL(basicly read only statements only) in a sandbox/with isolation? Things like subquery(really safe?), SQL Emulator(https://github.com/maciakl/jQuery-SQL-Emulator, buggy and slow), `ROLLBACK`(maybe slow also and hard to be safe also) and `CREATE TEMPORARY` would be a choice, but I hope to find something better.

This is real case:

I'm trying to make a report tool that is able to custom SQL by users(SELECT or JOIN or COUNT or SUM etc. and output as csv). However it's really dangerous to let users execute SQL in the production DB. Is there any better suggestion?

p.s. My platform is MySQL+PHP+JS

UPDATE:

The point is, I can create a read only MySQL account. But this cannot prevent users querying some rows supposed not accessible in a single table(e.g. check in records in a table, `where department_id = xx` and staffs list in a table, `where department_id = xx`).

Comment: Then what is the point of your tool if you won't use it on production DB?

Comment: Create a second database for testing.

Comment: I can use the production DB if there's a secure solution.

Comment: The point is, I can create a read only MySQL account. But this cannot prevent users querying some rows supposed not accessible in a single table(e.g. check in record in a table, where department_id = xx).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone come across this question.

1. check if there is any function/statement from list (your list should
   contain all the function/statement which can be used to get system info)
2. take input from user only for select as table_name.column_name
3. use these table name to create join query
4. add your filter condition in where e.g. excluding rows you don't want your user to see

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to set-up (at least) one slave of that production database. You can read about implementing master-slave replication here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html

You can use one slave to perform various actions on it instead of running them on the production database (which should be set-up as master):

- run your report tool
- run backups (you are doing regular backups of your database right?)
- run other tests

You can abuse that slave and even if you break it, it will not harm your production database.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution, trying to prove it is secure:

https://github.com/wilsonlmh/sqlSandbox